# Oracle SQL calculate the sum of days, hours, minutes between dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sum

I have this query to show an agent name `resolved_by`, and the count of services he/she resolved, in addition to that I want to show the sum of time spent between when the service is reported `creation_Date` and when its resolved `last_resolved_date` for all services resolved per agent,and I want to show that time in days,hours and minutes, how can I do that? the below query gives weird results

```
select resolved_by,
count(resolved_by) services_resolved,
 
     round(sum((last_resolved_date+0)-(creation_date+0)),0)  || 'Days' ||
    round(sum(((last_resolved_date+0)-(creation_date+0))*24),0) || 'Hours' ||
    round(sum(((last_resolved_date+0)-(creation_date+0))*24*60),0) || 'Minutes' effort
 from svc_service_requests

where status_type_cd = 'ORA_SVC_RESOLVED'

group by resolved_by
```

for example : `14 Days 327 Hours 19598 Minutes`

Comment: sry, i edited the post, new query and new results

Comment: What are the Oracle datatypes for 'last_reslved_date' and 'creation_date' ? From your example it seems that these are just numbers, not DATETIME columns.
It would be better to modify the datamodel so that these columns are DATETIME. Then you can use Oracle arithmetic operations on dates and date intervals (see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-B03DD036-66F8-4BD3-AF26-6D4433EBEC1C)

Comment: @dami Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type. It either has `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` and they both have a time component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an all purpose function that accepts either dates or timestamps and returns the difference

```
CREATE FUNCTION datediff (p_from timestamp, p_to timestamp)
return varchar2 is
  v_from     TIMESTAMP := LEAST(p_from, p_to);
  v_to       TIMESTAMP := GREATEST(p_from, p_to);
  l_years    PLS_INTEGER;
  l_from     TIMESTAMP;
  l_interval interval day(3) to second(6);
begin
  l_years    := TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(v_to, v_from)/12);
  l_from     := CAST(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(v_from, l_years * 12), 'MI') AS TIMESTAMP)
                  + NUMTODSINTERVAL( EXTRACT(SECOND FROM v_from), 'SECOND' );
  l_interval := (v_to - l_from) DAY(3) TO SECOND(6);
  return l_years || ' Years '
    || extract (day from l_interval) || ' Days '
    || extract (hour from l_interval) || ' Hours '
    || extract (minute from l_interval) || ' Minutes '
    || extract (second from l_interval) || ' Seconds';
end datediff;
/

SELECT 
datediff( TO_DATE('2022-04-03 10:11:13','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
TO_DATE('2001-05-10 17:48:09','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) as  diff FROM DUAL


DIFF
20 Years 327 Days 16 Hours 23 Minutes 4 Seconds
```

Comment: If you are going to re-post code that someone else has written as an answer to a different question, please provide an attribution to the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74163246/1509264).

Answer (score 0):

Use `MOD` to get the hours/minutes and `TRUNC` (or `FLOOR`):

```sql
select resolved_by,
       count(resolved_by) AS services_resolved,
       TRUNC(sum(last_resolved_date - creation_date)) || 'Days'
       || TRUNC(MOD(sum(last_resolved_date - creation_date)*24, 24)) || 'Hours'
       || TRUNC(MOD(sum(last_resolved_date - creation_date)*24*60, 60)) || 'Minutes'
         AS effort
from   svc_service_requests
where status_type_cd = 'ORA_SVC_RESOLVED'
group by resolved_by
```

If your columns are `TIMESTAMP`s then you can use `CAST(last_resolved_date AS DATE)` and `CAST(creation_date AS DATE)`.